# Set default "Quantity" dropdown select in product. Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce

Using the [Commerce Kickstart distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) I have a shop site listing products.
The product page shows a Quantity widget to allow the buyer to choose the product quantity to be added to the cart. (look my capture)

I need to change this widget to the standar select list html element. (look the capture)

**Update:** I found the library which generate this "spinner", is located at: **profiles/commerce_kickstart/libraries/jquery_ui_spinner** I don't see any module related to this. Maybe in theme?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know its already a year ago, but if someone bump in this question here's one of the solution, I don't know if there's a module that already existing changing the widget type of quantity in add to cart form but you can achieve this using
`hook_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter` like this

Example:

```
function example_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Change widget type of quantity to select list
  $form['quantity'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Quantity'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#datatype' => 'integer', // <-- I added this one to fix Notice: Undefined index: #datatype in commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate() when you click add to cart button
    '#options' => array(
      1 => '1',
      2 => '2',
      3 => '3',
      4 => '4',
      5 => '5'
    )
  );
}
```