# Commerce 2 | Quantity Dropdown with Default Values -> Error

Tags: 8, forms, commerce

I need to allow the costumers to choose specific quantities for specific type of products but I would like to avoid adding 2 extra modules to my website ( Commerce Extended Quantity & Extended Number Field). So I used a form alter function like here [Set default "Quantity" dropdown select in product. Commerce Kickstart](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176917/set-default-quantity-dropdown-select-in-product-commerce-kickstart).

The issue is that the input is transformed to a dropdown but when the form is submitted, a blank page appears with the message "The website encountered an unexpected error" and the error in admin/reports/dblog is `Cannot unset string offsets in Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->extractFormValues()...` Here is the code I use:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if (strpos($form_id, "commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form") !== false) {

  // Change widget type of quantity to select list
 $form['quantity'] = array(
'#title' => t('Quantity'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#datatype' => 'integer', // <-- I added this one to fix Notice: Undefined index: #datatype in commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_validate() when you click add to cart button
'#options' => array(
  1 => '1',
  2 => '2',
  3 => '3'
)
);   


 }}
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue:

```
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

 if (strpos($form_id, "commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form") !== false) {
$form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 1;
 $form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#step'] = 0.5;
   $form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#min'] = 1;
    $form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#max'] = 3;
    $form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#type'] = 'select';       
 $form['quantity']['widget'][0]['value']['#options'] = array(
 '1' => t('1 hour'),
'1.5' => t('1,5 hour'),   
  '2' => t('2 hours'),
   '2.5' => t('2,5 hours'),
   '3' => t('3 hours') );
    }}
```

Comment: A new issue now is that this code does not work for the cart view page. You can follow here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255265/cart-view-i-can-not-override-the-quantity-input-to-select-dropdown